# How to convert PdfContentBytes to Array of Bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, jpeg

I'm using iTextSharp DLLin asp.net.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
        //create footer
        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfStamper textStamp = new PdfStamper(reader, outStream);
        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName, false);
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            PdfContentByte pdfPageContents = textStamp.GetOverContent(i);            
//How to convert the PdfContentByte  to array of bytes here?
}
```

I want to convert each page of the PDF to JPEG. How to convert the PdfContentByte  to array of bytes here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your plan is going to work. Not everything that looks like it lives on a "page" actually lives on a page, some things live in a global shared location. So extracting a page's bytes would give you a corrupt document. You could [extract every page in a PDF](http://www.jamesewelch.com/2008/11/14/how-to-extract-pages-from-a-pdf-document/) to separate files which would bring over these shared resources but that still is in the PDF format. If you have already written a PDF-to-JPEG routine then maybe you're OK. If you haven't, then iTextSharp won't be able to help you.

iTextSharp doesn't (currently) "know" what a PDF "looks" like, it only knows the contents of the PDF. It "knows" that a run of text exists but it doesn't "know" how that should be rendered visually. It "knows" that a PDF might have two images but doesn't "know" or even care if they overlap, once again that's the renderer's problem.

Once again, if you've written a PDF-to-JPEG routine then disregard all that I'm saying. But the bytes of a PDF have nothing in common with the bytes of JPEG. Although a PDF may contain a JPEG it can also contain many other types of binary data. And that data is probably compressed inside of a stream, too.

Now, if you're [looking to just extract images from a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10692390/231316), that is something that iTextSharp can help you with.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
PdfStamper textStamp = new PdfStamper(reader, outStream);
byte[] content = outStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: I want the array of bytes for each page of PDF...?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `byte[]` of a `PdfContentByte` as follows:

```
pdfPageContents.getInternalBuffer().toByteArray();
```

Comment: Kind of late, but this did not return the bytes. But this -> `pdfBytes = pdfContentByte.InternalBuffer.Buffer;` did.