# Image extraction encoding issue with itextsharp

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext, jpeg

I extract the pictures found in a PDF document with itextsharp using this snippet (thanks @Scott Stanford from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16900951/1517335)) :

```
    private static IList<System.Drawing.Image> GetImagesFromPdfDict(PdfDictionary dict, PdfReader doc)
    {
        List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

        if (dict == null)
            return images;

        PdfDictionary res = (PdfDictionary)(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(dict.Get(PdfName.RESOURCES)));

        if (res == null)
            return images;

        PdfDictionary xobj = (PdfDictionary)(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(res.Get(PdfName.XOBJECT)));

        if (xobj == null)
            return images;

        foreach (PdfName name in xobj.Keys)
        {
            PdfObject obj = xobj.Get(name);
            if (obj.IsIndirect())
            {
                PdfDictionary tg = (PdfDictionary)(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj));
                PdfName subtype = (PdfName)(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(tg.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE)));
                if (PdfName.IMAGE.Equals(subtype))
                {
                    int xrefIdx = ((PRIndirectReference)obj).Number;
                    PdfObject pdfObj = doc.GetPdfObject(xrefIdx);
                    PdfStream str = (PdfStream)(pdfObj);

                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject pdfImage =
                        new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject((PRStream)str);

                    System.Drawing.Image img = pdfImage.GetDrawingImage();

                    images.Add(img);
                }
                else if (PdfName.FORM.Equals(subtype) || PdfName.GROUP.Equals(subtype))
                {
                    images.AddRange(GetImagesFromPdfDict(tg, doc));
                }
            }
        }


        return images;
    }
```

Then I save the extracted System.Drawing.Image into jpeg files like this :

```
image.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This works well for most pictures, but in some rare cases, the saved pictures look like this : [image: people1] [image: people2]

*(I have added the black stroke after the generation of the image because these pictures concern real people).*

The white color turns into pink, and the black colors turn into green shades.

I tried to save the System.Drawing.Image with several encodings (System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter, also with PNG...) but I did not managed to change its output. So I think this problem come from the extraction of the image from the PDF and the creation of the System.Drawing.Image.

To test if the pictures are not corrupted, I tried with the online PDF extractor http://www.extractpdf.com/. This tool managed to extract these pictures without any problem.

Does anybody have an idea to solve this issue ?

Comment: You'll have to show us the PDF.

Comment: @PauloSoares Unfortunately I can't upload the PDF as is as it contains confidential data, I'm looking for leads I can try on my own. But I tried to modify the PDF to remove critical information to show you guys, but I was able to extract the image correctly on the resulting PDF...